# Stopping a thread when another thread has finished in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to programming with Multi-Threading, so I don't really understand why my code is not working right.

I have looked and searched on this site for answers and on google too, but did not find anything (or I did not know that it was a correct answer for me), so I'm asking you experts.

I have to make the user input a number. This number will be the amount of organs in the Fibonacci that will be displayed on the screen, with 1 second delay between each. Another Thread will display on the screen the time passed so far, every 5 seconds.

I have used a loop, but this makes no sense because I need it to continue while the first thread is running and stop when its not.

I dont know how to stop the second thread when the first, that creates the fibonacci, has stopped.

I have tried to use `join()`, `notifyAll()`, `stop()` but I am clearly missing something. I will give the code (without the `join`, `notifyAll`, or `stop`, because it does not work for me).

This is the main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class MainFibonacci 
    {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        int num;
        System.out.println("How many numbers in Fibonacci would you like?");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        num=in.nextInt();
        FibTime f1=new FibTime();
        MakeFibonacci m1= new MakeFibonacci(num);
        m1.start();
        f1.start();
    }
}
```

The class that creates the Fibonacci:

```
public class MakeFibonacci extends Thread{
private int number;

//constructor
public MakeFibonacci(int num){
    this.number=num;
}

public void run()
{
    for  (int i=1;i<=number;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(fibonacci(i) +"  ");

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }

  //The actual method that creates the fibonacci
  public int fibonacci(int number)
  {
        if(number == 1 || number == 2)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        int num1=1, num2=1, next=1;

        for(int i = 3; i<= number; i++)
        {
            next = num1 + num2; 
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = next;

        }
        return next; 
    } 

}
```

The second class with the mwthos for how much time has passed:

```
public class FibTime extends Thread 
{
    private int timePassed=5;

    public void run()
    {
       for(int i=1;i<timePassed;i++)
       {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("Time so far is "+ (timePassed*i) +" seconds");              
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       }

    }

}
```

Comment: There is definitely smell in design.

Comment: What is that mean? @Taky

Comment: I see two options. (1) Have some common volatile boolean variable with initial value as true that is used by both the threads. Second thread (`FibTime`) loops till this variable is true instead of current for loop and the first thread (`MakeFibonacci`) marks this variable as false once it is out of its for loop. (2) Another option is to use one thread instead of two. The first thread (`MakeFibonacci`) will take care of both printing the fibonacci number every one second and "time so far.." message whenever i%5==0.

Comment: Is this about how to coordinate the execution of two threads or do you just want to count how much time it will take for your fibonacci thread to complete execution?

Answer (score 2):

You have created the object for FibTime in the main function itself.. Instead you can declare it as a member of MakeFibonacci class ,create the object for FibTime in the constructor of MakeFibonacci class and start it there itself..
Now you will have the object reference to the thread FibTime. You can stop the FibTime thread with that reference. Place the .stop() command after the for loop that prints the Fibonacci numbers..

Other way is by passing the object of FibTime thread that is executing as argument to the MakeFibonacci constructor and assign it to a member of MakeFibonacci.. Stopping this thread is by the same way..

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. i have some question please. im trying to figure out what you have said here, but i cant understand you ery well. im a little confused as you can see. can you please edit your answer and give the example for what you said? thanks.

Comment: Don't create object for FibTime in main class. Declare an object of FibTime as member MakeFibonacci class and start it in the constructor of MakeFibonacci.
Once the for loop that prints the no is complete stop the FibTime thread by stop() method. Eg: f1.stop()

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do would be:

```
public class Beginning {

private static volatile boolean itIsRunning = true;
final static CountDownLatch startGate = new CountDownLatch(1);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread fibonnaciThread = new Thread(new Fibonnaci(10));
    Thread timerThread = new Thread(new FibTimer());

    fibonnaciThread.start();
    timerThread.start();

    startGate.countDown();
    while (itIsRunning)
        ;

    timerThread.interrupt();

    System.out.println("Interuppted timer");
}

private static class Fibonnaci implements Runnable {

    private int target;

    public Fibonnaci(int target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            startGate.await();

            for (int i = 1; i <= target; i++) {
                System.out.print(fibonacci(i) + "  ");

                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }

            itIsRunning = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }

    // The actual method that creates the fibonacci
    private int fibonacci(int number) {
        if (number == 1 || number == 2) {
            return 1;
        }

        int num1 = 1, num2 = 1, next = 1;

        for (int i = 3; i <= number; i++) {
            next = num1 + num2;
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = next;

        }
        return next;
    }

}

private static class FibTimer extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        try {
            startGate.await();
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println("Time so far is " + System.nanoTime() + " seconds");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }
}
}
```

This works as you intended. The `CountDownLatch` is to make sure that both threads will start at the same time. However there are a few points that are wanting.

1. Using `Thread.sleep()` is not the best solution. You can use `shceduledExecutors`
2. This is not the best way to time how much the Fibonacci takes for a particular number but I have given it in this way in order to demonstrate how you could communicate completion among two different threads.

Note the `volatile`. If it is not volatile it will not work correctly. (without synchronization at least).